# Any free software for creating paid WIFI hotspot?

Tags: wireless-networking, hotspot

Anyone know free software (or very cheap) for creating paid access to WIFI - with tokens mechanism?

Can be on Linux, or Windows...

I have a small Hostel and I want to create paid access to wifi (like 1$ for hour).

Comment: I should downvote this question just because you're trying to be a cheapo and get stuff for free, but you're trying to charge others

Comment: @Markasoftware: You don't like someone's business model, so you take away their superuser reputation?

Comment: @iconoclast I never did downvote it though. Looking back at this, the only thing more pathetic than what I said is that you're responding to it 4 years later.

Comment: @Markasoftware: If you think your behavior is decent and acceptable, tell me why—its possible to have a rational discussion.  If you resort to name-calling then you just confirm everyone's original suspicions about you.   Calling someone pathetic is rude and uncalled-for, and has no place in rational discourse. Please delete your account now and never return to SE. We don't need this sort of behavior here.

Comment: @iconoclast What is the difference between wishing to downvote a post because of the morality of its content and wishing for somebody to delete their account because you do not agree with an observation they made?

I wonder, what did you expect as a response from your comment? It seems fairly clear you are just trying to start a petty argument.

Comment: (1) You believe it is immoral to use free software to resell bandwidth?  Good luck making a coherent case for that.  I suppose then you think that the (probably) millions of businesses that use free software are also committing a great sin.  Are you going to take punitive action against them too? (2) Rather than talk about issues and ideas, you choose to resort to name-calling.  You can't be bothered to engage in rational dialog, so you attack instead.  That's really not how civil society works.  Since you can't be respectful, or rational, it's best for everyone if you leave.

Answer (score 6):

The most popular replacement firmware for relatively common routers, [OpenWrt](http://openwrt.org/) and [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/), do provide support for establishing hotspots. There is quite a lot of documentation on this to be found on their respective Wikis:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Chillispot

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Captive_Portal#Provider

A lot of what was once quite hard to do, has been packaged up by [EasyHotspot](http://easyhotspot.inov.asia/) into an all in one hotspot management system.

Comment: EasyHotspot seems nice. Its requirements state *"Wireless Access Point (you don't need wireless router feature but a Wireless AP)."* I guess this should read *"you cannot use an existing wireless router, but you need a standalone Wireless AP"*?

Comment: It just refers to the way you should configure the router/AP. Some where in the firmware should be an option that allows your device to function in one of several modes, Router or Access point etc.

Comment: Ah, my comment was phrased quite badly. I meant to ask: if one has a modem with *a built-in* wireless router (which is connected to the internet) then one would need a separate wireless device to be the access point for EasyHotspot, right? (Just curious; not saying it's bad.)

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood. I guess it would depend upon the options available in the modem/router, but in all honesty, I believe a dedicated device would be the better option.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal at the end is good list of alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you asked for, as it's not based on tokens, but: you could join [FON](http://www.fon.com/en/), and open up your (cheap<sup>†</sup>) Fonera router [for paid access](http://www.fon.com/en/info/makeMoney) (not limited to you own guests, if the Wifi range is good).

A software solution I never tried, and which seems a bit hard to set up for a regular user, is [CoovaChilli](http://coova.org/CoovaChilli). It needs a WPA Enterprise router, and then offers authentication services to selectively --through a so-called captive portal-- share your access point.

<sup>†</sup> [Old Fonera routers](https://shop.fon.com/FonShop/shop/EN/ShopController?view=product&product=PRD-018) are just €30, the newest €79 / $99.

Answer (score 1):

[HotSpotPA](http://www.hotspotpa.com/hspacost.aspx) is a hosted solution that costs under $99 per router. It is software that runs on both Linksys and Ubiquiti router hardware. Because it is hosted it doesn't require any Windows or Linux software, all the behind-the-scenes authentication and payment processing is done by the HotSpotPA company through an encrypted VPN that is built into the router. No tokens though, it requires the customer to use credit cards or PayPal.