# Free Wi-Fi multi-user management software

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, kiosk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any free software for creating paid WIFI hotspot?](https://superuser.com/questions/151746/any-free-software-for-creating-paid-wifi-hotspot)

With timelimit and a key for each user? Is there such a thing out there? Kinda like an internet kiosk, but for Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various Linux-based routers that can run the [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) firmware, to which you can add [ChilliSpot](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Chillispot).  However, it has not been updated for a long time and the project is dead.

A new alternative is [**CoovaChilli**](http://coova.org/CoovaChilli), which is a fork of ChilliSpot which is actively being developed.  It runs on the [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/) firmware.

The easiest option would be to get a suitable router and install the [**CooveAP**](http://coova.org/CoovaAP) firmware, which is specialised for wifi hotspots.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and I hope it helps others!